# How can I set error message if it is not belongs to training datasets?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, rdkit

I have been implemented successfully recommendation engine but having a problem with that if I put any unrelated value still giving output it must be shown that " you have entered wrong value"

Here is output
[correct smiles output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzbOc.png)

If I put wrong smiles or anything which does not belong to the training dataset then it must be given a message that please enter correct smiles.

[Wrong output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ktDQ.png)

I have entered any random text so if I enter wrong smiles it must come result as

result: "Please enter correct smiles"

I am putting my code I try If else but not working.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import Draw

import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort
import json
import sys
import random
import unicodedata
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

data = pd.read_csv("clean_o2h.csv", sep=",")


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])



def predict_word():
    print(request.get_json())
    sent = request.get_json()['smiles']
    reactants = data["reactants"].tolist()
    targets = data["targets"].tolist()
    error = ("plese enter correct smiles") 

# TFIDF vector representation
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    X = vectorizer.fit_transform(targets)

    test = vectorizer.transform([sent])

#test = vectorizer.transform(["NC1=CC=C2C(COC(N[C@H]3C4=C(CC3)C=CC=C4)=N2)=C1"])

    cosine_similarities = cosine_similarity(test, X).flatten()
    l = []
   # n = ["Result 1","Result 2", "Result 3","Result 4"]

# Extract top 5 similarity records
    similarity = cosine_similarities.argsort()[:-5:-1]
     #print("Top 5 recommendations...")
    for sim in similarity:
    #print(reactants[sim])
       result = reactants[sim]
       l.append(result)
       print(l)

      # output = dict(zip(l,n))
       res = { i : l[i] for i in range(0, len(l) ) }



   # return  jsonify({"Recommendation": res})

    if(sent == targets):
      return jsonify({"Recommendation": res})
    else:
          return jsonify({"Error": error})




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port='8080')
```

Please help me with correct logic here target variable is the smiles and reactants variable is a recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check whether the `SMILES` are valid by parsing the molecule using RDKit.
This should answer part of your question, but I'm sorry I don't understand what else you are trying to achieve here.

```
from rdkit import Chem

error = 'something is wrong'
smiles = request.get_json()['smiles']
m = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
if m is None:
    return jsonify({"Error": error})
else:
    # you have valid smiles
    pass
```